# Strange Segmentation Fault in PyArray_SimpleNewFromData

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cython

My question is similar "in spirit" to [Segmentation fault in PyArray_SimpleNewFromData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467199/segmentation-fault-in-pyarray-simplenewfromdata)

I have a C code that looks like this: (original code actually tests if `malloc()` returned NULL)

```
  1 #include <Python.h>
  2 #include <numpy/arrayobject.h>  // (Not sure if right import)
  3 #include <stdlib.h>
  4 #include <stdio.h>
  5 
  6 double *calculate_dW(npy_intp *dim_w) {
  7         int i;
  8         double* data = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * dim_w[0]);
  9         
 10         /* Inserts some dummy data */
 11         for (i = 0; i < dim_w[0]; i++)
 12                 data[i] = i;
 13         
 14         return data;
 15 }
```

And then a Cython code that wraps it inside a function:

```
  1 import cython
  2 import numpy as np
  3 cimport numpy as np
  4 
  5 cdef extern double *calculate_dW(np.npy_intp *dim_w)
  6 
  7 def run_calculate_dW(np.ndarray[np.npy_intp, ndim=1, mode="c"] dim_w):
  8         print("Will call calculate_dW")
  9         cdef double *dW = calculate_dW(&dim_w[0])
 10 
 11         print("Will call PyArray_SimpleNewFromData")
 12         ret = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(
 13                 1,
 14                 &dim_w[0],
 15                 np.NPY_FLOAT64,
 16                 dW)
 17         print("Will print")
 18         print(ret)
 19         print("Will return")
 20         return ret
```

Which I test with

```
  # runTest.py
  1 import numpy as np
  2 import multiply
  3 a = np.array((10,)) # as expected, using `np.array(10)` won't work
  4 print a
  5 multiply.run_calculate_dW(a)
```

And get the following output

```
$ PYTHONPATH=build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ python runTest.py 
[10]
Will call calculate_dW
Will call PyArray_SimpleNewFromData
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

(i.e., a SegFault in the call to PyArray_SimpleNewFromData() (if I replace it by, say, `ret = 1`, the Segmentation Fault vanishes). When debugging, I tried many things:

- Changing the number of dimensions to 1;
- Increasing the amount of memory allocated by `malloc()` (to guarantee I was not accessing anything I shouldn't);
- Changing `np.NPY_FLOAT32` to `np.float32`;
- Changing the way I pass the "shape" of the new array.

I believe I am following precisely the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html), as well as [the answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357115/pyarray-simplenewfromdata-example). I don't seem to get any compiler error or warning.

*Still, I do have noticed that all other codes around in the internet are using C (instead of Python) when they call PyArray_SimpleNewFromData. I tried returning a `PyObject*` from the C function, but couldn't get it to compile.*

Also, I do get some "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" warning; but I have read I am safe to ignore them. ([Cython Numpy warning about NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API when using MemoryView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789055/cython-numpy-warning-about-npy-no-deprecated-api-when-using-memoryview) )

Any suggestion? (also, any other way of creating a numpy array out of `dW`?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're passing a Python list as the second argument to `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` when it expects a pointer to an integer. I'm a little surprised this compiles.

Try:

```
ret = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(
                     4,
                     &dim_w[0], # pointer to first element
                     np.NPY_FLOAT64,
                     dW)
```

Note that I've also changed the type to `NPY_FLOAT64` since that should match `double`.

I'd also change the definition of `dim_w` to

```
np.ndarray[np.NPY_INTP, ndim=1, mode="c"] dim_w
```

to ensure that the type of the array matches what numpy is expecting. This may also require changing the signature of `calculate_dW` to `double *calculate_dW(intptr_t *dim_w)` to match too.

---

**Edit:** A second issue is that you need to include the line

```
np.import_array()
```

in your Cython file (just at the top level, after your imports). This does some setup stuff for numpy. In principle I think the documentation recommends you always include it when doing `cimport numpy`. In practice it only sometimes matter, and this is one of those times.

---

(Answer is now tested)

Comment: I put some "fully testable" code. Even with your suggestion, the Segmentation Fault persists. I am still stuck with this problem =/

Comment: Ohh... wow... I would never have found that out. Thanks a lot =)